# Python AES 256 CBC Encryption - ValueError: Incorrect AES key length

Tags: python, encryption, aes, sha256

i want to write encryption for my plaintext using AES 256 on Python 3.8.5, but when i executed it i received error **ValueError: Incorrect AES key length (64 bytes)** is there something wrong in my code ?

```
plaintext = "ABC123"
secret_key = "6789045129812345"
secret_iv = "4567891122315731"
    
key = hashlib.sha256(str(secret_key).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
iv = hashlib.sha256(str(secret_iv).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
substring_iv = iv[:16]
cipher_config = AES.new(key.encode("utf-8"), AES.MODE_CBC, substring_iv.encode("utf-8"))
results = base64.b64encode(cipher_config)

print("results : "+results)
```

Comment: The hex digest is twice as long as the digest.

Comment: **Security warning** using of static keys and iv is **UNSECURE**, you should use a password derivation function like PBKDF2 combined with a randomly generated Salt to get an acceptable security level, thanks.

Comment: @MichaelFehr okay, its just simple example for encryption after my problem solved i will changes into random generated salt..but i still have that error..any idea ?

Comment: If you derived your key with a function created for deriving keys, you will get a key of the correct length - thus solving your problem. Right now you try to derive a key using a sha256 and get a 'key' of the wrong size ..

Comment: Probably the most striking thing about your code is that you do not use or encrypt the plaintext anywhere, i.e. the encrypt() call is missing. Also, the padding of the plaintext is lacking. And finally the length of the key is not correct, see the other comments. The PyCryptodome documentation contains easy to understand examples for AES and most modes, e.g. [here for AES-CBC](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/classic.html#cbc-mode).

Answer (score 5):

The following code is a full running example for a PBKDF2 key derivation with a random salt, followed by an AES 256 CBC-mode encryption. The code is running on my online compiler with Python 3.8.2 and uses the crypto-library **pycryptodome** version 3.9.9 for the crypto-tasks (https://www.pycryptodome.org).

The encryption output is separated (salt, iv and ciphertext) and each in Base64 encoding as the code is used in my cross-platform-project.

This is the output:

```
SO AES CBC 256 encryption with PBKDF2 key derivation
plaintext: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

* * * Encryption * * *
ciphertext: 2BUSFaOSh+HsFI0tYbuZEJxvjRfYxJxwP+4h8haaTgU=:1Ke2VbQouUGh/ninKt1RiQ==:Wno0ARfn3dCCGm/IGpIpuN9guoBsRrktL1RaIaFflQIRl9uOettvsH9AexcH/bvq
output is (Base64) salt : (Base64) iv : (Base64) ciphertext

* * * Decryption * * *
ciphertext (Base64): 2BUSFaOSh+HsFI0tYbuZEJxvjRfYxJxwP+4h8haaTgU=:1Ke2VbQouUGh/ninKt1RiQ==:Wno0ARfn3dCCGm/IGpIpuN9guoBsRrktL1RaIaFflQIRl9uOettvsH9AexcH/bvq
input is (Base64) salt : (Base64) iv : (Base64) ciphertext
plaintext:  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

Kindly note that the code has no exception handling, has not run an authentication check and is for educational purpose only:

```
from Crypto.Protocol.KDF import PBKDF2
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad
from Crypto.Util.Padding import unpad
import base64

# uses https://www.pycryptodome.org version 3.9.9

def base64Encoding(input):
  dataBase64 = base64.b64encode(input)
  dataBase64P = dataBase64.decode("UTF-8")
  return dataBase64P

def base64Decoding(input):
    return base64.decodebytes(input.encode("ascii"))

def generateSalt32Byte():
  return get_random_bytes(32)

def aesCbcPbkdf2EncryptToBase64(password, plaintext):
  passwordBytes = password.encode("ascii")
  salt = generateSalt32Byte()
  PBKDF2_ITERATIONS = 15000
  encryptionKey = PBKDF2(passwordBytes, salt, 32, count=PBKDF2_ITERATIONS, hmac_hash_module=SHA256)
  cipher = AES.new(encryptionKey, AES.MODE_CBC)
  ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(pad(plaintext.encode("ascii"), AES.block_size))
  ivBase64 = base64Encoding(cipher.iv)
  saltBase64 = base64Encoding(salt)
  ciphertextBase64 = base64Encoding(ciphertext)
  return saltBase64 + ":" + ivBase64 + ":" + ciphertextBase64

def aesCbcPbkdf2DecryptFromBase64(password, ciphertextBase64): 
  passwordBytes = password.encode("ascii")
  data = ciphertextBase64.split(":")
  salt = base64Decoding(data[0])
  iv = base64Decoding(data[1])
  ciphertext = base64Decoding(data[2])
  PBKDF2_ITERATIONS = 15000
  decryptionKey = PBKDF2(passwordBytes, salt, 32, count=PBKDF2_ITERATIONS, hmac_hash_module=SHA256)
  cipher = AES.new(decryptionKey, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
  decryptedtext = unpad(cipher.decrypt(ciphertext), AES.block_size)
  decryptedtextP = decryptedtext.decode("UTF-8")
  return decryptedtextP

print("SO AES CBC 256 encryption with PBKDF2 key derivation")

plaintext = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
print("plaintext: " + plaintext)
password = "6789045129812345"

print("\n* * * Encryption * * *") 
ciphertextBase64 = aesCbcPbkdf2EncryptToBase64(password, plaintext)
print("ciphertext: " + ciphertextBase64)
print("output is (Base64) salt : (Base64) iv : (Base64) ciphertext")

print("\n* * * Decryption * * *") 
ciphertextDecryptionBase64 = ciphertextBase64

print("ciphertext (Base64): " + ciphertextDecryptionBase64)
print("input is (Base64) salt : (Base64) iv : (Base64) ciphertext")
decryptedtext = aesCbcPbkdf2DecryptFromBase64(password, ciphertextBase64)
print("plaintext:  " + decryptedtext)
```

Comment: Lovely - thanks Michael - one minor edit: Line 39 should be "data = ciphertextBase64.split(":")" to encapsulate it into the function

Answer (score 0):

You need to use 32 bytes(256 bits) or 16 bytes (128 bits).
A good way would be using the python `os.urandom` function.

key = os.urandom(32)

Notice that after you do that, you don't need to do key.encode in this line:

```
cipher_config = AES.new(key.encode("utf-8"), AES.MODE_CBC, substring_iv.encode("utf-8"))
```

This will do the trick:

```
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
```